# How to convert a Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}} to Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},1} in julia

Tags: tuples, julia

How may I convert a `Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}` to `Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},1}` ?

Code

```
#Sampling
function sam()
    x = range(0, 10.0, length = 9) |> collect
    y = range(0, 10.0, length = 9) |> collect
    return (x,y)
end
xy = sam()
typeof(xy)
```

The code above returns this output:

```
Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do in your situation is to assign the output of your function to two separate variables, like this:

```
function foo()
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    y = [4, 5, 6]
    return x, y
end

x, y = foo()
```

[See the docs on multiple return values.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Multiple-Return-Values)

Then you can use `zip` to turn the vectors into an iterator of tuples:

```
julia> x, y = foo()
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

julia> x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> y
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 5
 6

julia> z = zip(x, y)
zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Note that the output of `zip` is an iterator, rather than an array of tuples. You can either iterate through the elements of the iterator to get the individual tuples,

```
julia> foreach(println, z)
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
```

or you can collect the iterator if you actually need an array of tuples:

```
julia> collect(z)
3-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 4)
 (2, 5)
 (3, 6)
```